Correlation decay in GHZ states, IBM quantum video
I watched an IBM quantum tutorial "Hello World" video. It assumed and then demonstrated that the correlation decays with the distance between two Pauli Z observables. I'm not able to derive the decay, even though intuitively it makes sense.
(It's a "Hello World" video with qiskit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93-zLTppFZw )
For the ease of notation assume 4 qubits
$$|GHZ \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00000 \rangle +|11111 \rangle)$$
Let's look at the extreme, when two Pauli Zs are furthest apart.
Expectation of sparse Pauli Z-s is defined as
$$ \langle GHZ|Z\otimes I \otimes I \otimes Z |GHZ \rangle $$
We have $Z|0 \rangle =|0 \rangle $ and $Z|1 \rangle =-|1 \rangle $, hence:
$$Z\otimes I \otimes I \otimes Z |GHZ \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00000 \rangle +(-1)(-1)|11111 \rangle) = |GHZ \rangle $$
And that results into
$$ \langle GHZ|Z\otimes I \otimes I \otimes Z |GHZ \rangle =  \langle GHZ|GHZ \rangle = 1$$
What am I doing wrong?

You are assuming all gates are noiseless, but in reality each CX gate introduces noise that decoheres the GHZ state. The more gates you add, the closer this measure is to 0

The observation that correlations decay due to noise is also the driving observation of this work: https://arxiv.org/abs/2407.12768.
